# Is Spring Boot emptying "password" fields in the request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is Spring by default filtering out a field called "password" from the request? it is always null. I think I read something about that before. But how can I disable it for this specific endpoint?

The screenshot shows the request on the right and the debugger output on the left for the `SingUpRequest`. `password` is always empty and I don't understand why. I'm just starting with Spring, trying to get out of the PHP world.

[image]

Controller Signature:

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
public String SignUp(
    @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUp
)
```

```
public class SignUpRequest {
    public Account account;
    public Organization organization;
    public UserProfile userProfile;

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }
}
```

Account Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @Id()
    public String accountId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    public String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "A password is required")
    public String password;

    public String confirmPassword;

    public String test;

    public String emailVerificationToken;

    public LocalDateTime emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String setPassword(String password) {
        return password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationTokenExpiresAt(LocalDateTime emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt) {
        this.emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt = emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEmailVerificationTokenExpiresAt() {
        return emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;
    }

    public boolean checkIfEmailVerificationTokenIsExpired() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "accountId='" + accountId + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", emailVerificationToken='" + emailVerificationToken + '\'' +
                ", emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt=" + emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The JSON I'm sending via Postman:

```
{
    "account": {
        "email": "fk@kreative-design.net",
        "password": "password",
        "confirmPassword": "password",
        "test": "test"
    },
    "organization": {
        "name": "Phauthentic"
    },
    "userProfile": {
        "firstName": "Florian",
        "lastName": "Krämer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: are you able to sign up?

Comment: Maybe you have an `OncePerRequestFilter` in place which strips out the password details? Or something else even prior within the Server itself.

Comment: No, it won't work because it throws an exception because the password can't be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a Getter is a Getter, and a Setter should act like a Setter. Try this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @Id()
    public String accountId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    public String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "A password is required")
    public String password;

    public String confirmPassword;

    public String test;

    public String emailVerificationToken;

    public LocalDateTime emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationTokenExpiresAt(LocalDateTime emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt) {
        this.emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt = emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEmailVerificationTokenExpiresAt() {
        return emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt;
    }

    public boolean checkIfEmailVerificationTokenIsExpired() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "accountId='" + accountId + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", emailVerificationToken='" + emailVerificationToken + '\'' +
                ", emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt=" + emailVerificationTokenExpiresAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Note the difference in the `setPassword` method.

Also, you're mixing up the access types of the related fields. Eg. for **confirmPassword** there are no Getter/Setter in place, so the ORM falls back to direct field reflection settlement. Use either the one or the other. When there is no specific reason to go with Getter/setter, add `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` to the class. Otherwise provide Getter/Setter for all fields. Anyhow, try to stay consistent.

Comment: Oh my god...  thanks for proving that late night coding isn't always a good idea... I feel like an idiot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @floriank On a side note; if you're using spring-boot, there's no reason to manually write getters and setters.  Include the `org.projectlombok:lombok` dependency (it's defined in the parent BOM).  Then add the annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter` to your class.  Read up on the lombok stuff, it will save you a ton of time, make your code cleaner, and prevent issues like this from ever happening).

Comment: Thanks again. I'll give it a try! Out of curiosity, what is the downside of using it? Adding more abstractions and libs comes always with an impact.

Comment: The downside is that you have to obey an additional library. It's a precompilation processor which modifies your code according to specific annotations. It may be useful at first glance, but can be limiting in some cases. Modern IDEs are very good at adding requried Getter/Setter/Constructor with one keystroke. Also, they can hide these boilerplate code using regions from you. So there is not really a good reason anymore to use Lombok. I'd suggest to do not and have the final code already in place, fully tinkerable at your will, and not having another dependency which hides code for you.

Comment: Also you shouldn't rely on Lombok for Hashcode and Equals. Imo it's always better to do these manually, so you have to think about which fields are really necessary and thus getting almost always better performance.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms my concerns and guesses I had about using this library. Sounds nice for prototyping but not for production.